# How to pass a null value to a Spring controller from html form

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, forms, jdbctemplate

In my app, i have a form where users can insert or not value; so, the values are optional (eventually, a user can no insert value and obtain, on SQL side, a `select *`).

To do this, i have used Spring JdbcTemplates and the syntax:

```
(? is null or name_variable = ?)
```

and after tests, this works on backend side.

The problem is that with this syntax, if i want to allow the user to NOT insert the value x in the form, i must pass to controller (that use the DAO's method with this syntax) a `null` value. If i have as input type, in my form, `text`, how can i perform this?

Comment: Can't you simply map empty `""` input text value as `null` in your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using this code:

```
 @InitBinder
        public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
            binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a particular field in the form for which you want to pass a null value, check at the controller's side using an *if-else* and `toString()` if value **x** is present and instead pass `null` to the database.

Comment: Uhm so, if i have an input value "Info", with id (in the form) "infoname" and in my controller i have:

@RequestParam(name="infoname", required=false) String info

how i must make the control?

Comment: I just hope I am understanding what you're saying:
do something like if(name.toString()=="Info") {name="";}